# Failsafe - fallback not triggered after retry policy exceeds max. retries

Tags: java, fallback, retry-logic, java-failsafe

I want to perform an action that can be retried for a maximum of three times. I use the Failsafe library to implement a `RetryPolicy` as shown below:

```
private static FailsafeExecutor<List<String>> includeFailsafe() {
    RetryPolicy<List<String>> retryPolicy = RetryPolicy.<List<String>>builder()
            .handleResultIf(Predicate.not(List::isEmpty))
            .withMaxAttempts(MAX_RETRIES)
            .withBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(200L), Duration.ofMillis(4000L))
            .onFailedAttempt(e -> log.warn("some warning message"))
            .onRetriesExceeded(e -> log.error("some error message"))
            .build();
    Fallback<List<String>> fallback = Fallback.ofException(e -> new Exception());
    return Failsafe.with(fallback, retryPolicy);
}
```

Failsafe is then used for the following method:

```
private void publishIncludeFailsafe(List<String> x) {
        includeFailsafe().get(ctx -> {
            List<String> input = ctx.isRetry() ? ctx.getLastResult() : x;
            PublishBatchResponse response = publishBatch(input);
            if (response.hasFailed()) {
                return response.failed().stream().map(BatchResultErrorEntry::message).toList();
            }
            return List.of();
        });
    }
```

I use a unit test to mock the behavior when all retries fail, and I can see the error message that is logged when retries have been exceeded. So far, this seems to work.

However, I want to throw a custom exception when this scenario occurs through a fallback. However, the fallback is never triggered and it seems like I am doing something wrong here.

Why is the fallback never 'triggered' after retries have exceeded their maximum? And how can I still manage to throw the exception?

Comment: Could you please extend your question with the mentioned unit test?